# How to handle downloads in web component in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I wrote a sample servlet which can serve by giving an option to download a pdf file. I want to download that pdf file in to my cn1 app through webBrowser component. Later I want to view that pdf in the browser itself. If possible can you share sample example.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `Util.downloadToFilesystem`API giving a path you generate into the app home from the `FileSystemStorage` class.

Once download is complete you can just use `Display.execute` with that path.